# When players use reset board function on my Tic Tac Toe/ Connect Four game, the game counts every button click as win?

Tags: c#

The code works perfectly until the player uses the 'reset board' function the game decides that the any button click afterwards is a winner and the only way to stop this is to close and re-build the application (using visual studio). This is using a WPF application.

I don't know exactly what is causing the issue, but i have a feeling it has something to do with the checkforwinner method and how it checks that all buttons in a row or column by matching all colours. When the board is reset, it changes the colour of all the buttons to color.lightgray which may interfere with the checkforwinner function.

If it is not too much trouble i would also like to add a 'dropping' mechanic like the real connect four and make a more efficient checkforwinner function so i can expand the board to 12 x 8 or so and not have double or triple the amount of checkforwinner if statements, cheers.

Code is below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool turn = true; //if true it is red turn / if false it is yellow turn
    int turn_count = 0; //counts each turn for features such as draw function 
    bool winner_found = false; // automatically sets winner found function to false to 
    int win_method;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        win_method = rnd.Next(1, 4);

        if (win_method == 1)
        {
            winMethod.Text = "Horizontal Wins Only";
        }
        else if (win_method == 2)
        {
            winMethod.Text = "Vertical Wins Only";
        }
        else if (win_method == 3)
        {
            winMethod.Text = "Diagonal Wins Only";
        }
    }

    // function to alternate turns between red and yellow players and count turns for potential draws (see below). 
    // Also run checkForWinner function after every move (button click)
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (turn)
            b.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        else
            b.BackColor = Color.Red;

        turn = !turn;
        b.Enabled = false;
        turn_count++;
        checkForWinner();
    }

    private void checkForWinner()
    {
        if (win_method == 1)

            //check for horizontal wins
            if ((A1.BackColor == A2.BackColor) && (A2.BackColor == A3.BackColor) && (A3.BackColor == A4.BackColor) && (A4.BackColor == A5.BackColor) && (!A1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((B1.BackColor == B2.BackColor) && (B2.BackColor == B3.BackColor) && (B3.BackColor == B4.BackColor) && (B4.BackColor == B5.BackColor) && (!B1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((C1.BackColor == C2.BackColor) && (C2.BackColor == C3.BackColor) && (C3.BackColor == C4.BackColor) && (C4.BackColor == C5.BackColor) && (!C1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((D1.BackColor == D2.BackColor) && (D2.BackColor == D3.BackColor) && (D3.BackColor == D4.BackColor) && (D4.BackColor == D5.BackColor) && (!D1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((E1.BackColor == E2.BackColor) && (E2.BackColor == E3.BackColor) && (E3.BackColor == E4.BackColor) && (E4.BackColor == E5.BackColor) && (!E1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;

        if (win_method == 2)

            //check for vertical wins
            if ((A1.BackColor == B1.BackColor) && (B1.BackColor == C1.BackColor) && (C1.BackColor == D1.BackColor) && (D1.BackColor == E1.BackColor) && (!A1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((A2.BackColor == B2.BackColor) && (B2.BackColor == C2.BackColor) && (C2.BackColor == D2.BackColor) && (D2.BackColor == E2.BackColor) && (!A2.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((A3.BackColor == B3.BackColor) && (B3.BackColor == C3.BackColor) && (C3.BackColor == D3.BackColor) && (D3.BackColor == E3.BackColor) && (!A3.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((A4.BackColor == B4.BackColor) && (B4.BackColor == C4.BackColor) && (C4.BackColor == D4.BackColor) && (D4.BackColor == E4.BackColor) && (!A4.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((A5.BackColor == B5.BackColor) && (B5.BackColor == C5.BackColor) && (C5.BackColor == D5.BackColor) && (D5.BackColor == E5.BackColor) && (!A5.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;

        if (win_method == 3)

            //check for diagonal wins
            if ((A1.BackColor == B2.BackColor) && (B2.BackColor == C3.BackColor) && (C3.BackColor == D4.BackColor) && (D4.BackColor == E5.BackColor) && (!A1.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;
            else if ((A5.BackColor == B4.BackColor) && (B4.BackColor == C3.BackColor) && (C3.BackColor == D2.BackColor) && (D2.BackColor == E1.BackColor) && (!A5.Enabled))
                winner_found = true;



        // when winner string is detected to be true than find player who 
        //won and give players a message box to show this.
            // also adds one point to the player who wins the round 
        if (winner_found)
        {
            disableButtons();

            String winner = "";
            if (turn)
            {
                winner = Color.Red.ToString();
                red_win_count.Text = (Int32.Parse(red_win_count.Text) + 1).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                winner = Color.Yellow.ToString();
                yellow_win_count.Text = (Int32.Parse(yellow_win_count.Text) + 1).ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {  // if all squares are filled (25 moves) than signal draw as no more moves can be made
            if (turn_count == 25)
                MessageBox.Show("Draw! Wanna rematch?", "Rematch!");
        }
    }

    // function to disable all buttons for when winner is detected
    private void disableButtons()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                Button b = (Button)c;
                b.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    // help -> how to play: instructions on how to play the game in brief terms
    private void howToPlayToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connect Five is quite similar to the good old-fashioned Connect Four, " +
            "but there is a lot more spaces for you to play you pieces and you have to connect " +
            "five to win! The twist is, that you can only win a certain way, dependent on the " +
            "randomly generated direction on the right hand side of the screen. If the direction is " +
            "vertical, then you can only win with 5 coloured squares in a vertical line. Same with " +
            "horizontal and diagonal directions! Have Fun!", "Connect Five: How To Play");
    }
    // help -> about: quick about menu of the game, creator and copyright year/ symbol
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Made by Brendan Ellis © 2019", "Connect Five About");
    }
    // visual studio has a hissy fit if i dont put this in because it recognises this as a menu strip. 
    // This and the button_click function clash and i haven't been able to find a fix.
    private void fileToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    // file -> new game: resets complete game board to have a rematch
    private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        turn = true;
        turn_count = 0;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        win_method = rnd.Next(1, 4);

        if (win_method == 1)
        {
            winMethod.Text = "Horizontal Wins Only";
        }
        else if (win_method == 2)
        {
            winMethod.Text = "Vertical Wins Only";
        }
        else if (win_method == 3)
        {
            winMethod.Text = "Diagonal Wins Only";
        }

        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            try
            {
                Button b = (Button)c;
                b.Enabled = true;
                b.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    // file -> exit game: just exits the game because clicking the cross is obviously sooooo last year
    private void exitGameToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    // visual studio has a hissy fit if i dont put this in because it recognises this as a menu strip. 
    // This and the button_click function clash and i haven't been able to find a fix.
    private void helpToolStrip_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Enabled)
        {
            if (turn)
                b.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            else
                b.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void button_leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Enabled)
        {
            b.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
    }

    private void resetWinCountersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yellow_win_count.Text = "0";
        red_win_count.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you reset `winner_found` back to `false` upon restart?

Comment: There's no "reset board" function that I can see?

Comment: @Enigmativity when i say reset board function i mean the menustrip function near the bottom that effectively resets the board - sorry should have been more specific.

Comment: @ Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen - thank you so much! I didn't realise how easy the fix was, this fixed everything and the game works as it should!

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this code:

```
public enum WinMethod
{
    Horizontal,
    Vertical,
    Diagonal,
}
public enum Player
{
    Yellow,
    Red,
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Player turn = Player.Red;
    int turn_count = 0; //counts each turn for features such as draw function 
    bool winner_found = false; // automatically sets winner found function to false to 
    private WinMethod win_method;

    private Dictionary<Player, int> _winnerCount = new Dictionary<Player, int>()
    {
        { Player.Yellow, 0 },
        { Player.Red, 0 },
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private static Random __rnd = new Random();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        win_method =
            new[] { WinMethod.Horizontal, WinMethod.Vertical, WinMethod.Diagonal }
                .OrderBy(_ => __rnd.Next())
                .First();
    }

    // function to alternate turns between red and yellow players and count turns for potential draws (see below). 
    // Also run checkForWinner function after every move (button click)
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.BackColor = turn == Player.Red ? Color.Red : Color.Yellow;
        turn = turn == Player.Red ? Player.Yellow : Player.Red;
        b.Enabled = false;
        turn_count++;
        checkForWinner();
    }

    private void checkForWinner()
    {
        var grid = new[]
        {
            new { line = new [] { A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 }, method = WinMethod.Horizontal },
            new { line = new [] { B1, B2, B3, B4, B5 }, method = WinMethod.Horizontal },
            new { line = new [] { C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 }, method = WinMethod.Horizontal },
            new { line = new [] { D1, D2, D3, D4, D5 }, method = WinMethod.Horizontal },
            new { line = new [] { E1, E2, E3, E4, E5 }, method = WinMethod.Horizontal },
            new { line = new [] { A1, B1, C1, D1, E1 }, method = WinMethod.Vertical },
            new { line = new [] { A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 }, method = WinMethod.Vertical },
            new { line = new [] { A3, B3, C3, D3, E3 }, method = WinMethod.Vertical },
            new { line = new [] { A4, B4, C4, D4, E4 }, method = WinMethod.Vertical },
            new { line = new [] { A5, B5, C5, D5, E5 }, method = WinMethod.Vertical },
            new { line = new [] { A1, B2, C3, D4, E5 }, method = WinMethod.Diagonal },
            new { line = new [] { E1, D2, C3, B4, A5 }, method = WinMethod.Diagonal },
        };

        winner_found =
            grid.Any(g => g.method == win_method && g.line.Select(x => x.BackColor).Distinct().Count() == 1);

        if (winner_found)
        {
            disableButtons();

            _winnerCount[turn] += 1;
            (turn == Player.Red ? red_win_count : yellow_win_count).Text = _winnerCount[turn].ToString();
        }
        else
        {  // if all squares are filled (25 moves) than signal draw as no more moves can be made
            if (turn_count == 25)
                MessageBox.Show("Draw! Wanna rematch?", "Rematch!");
        }
    }

    // function to disable all buttons for when winner is detected
    private void disableButtons()
    {
        foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            b.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    // help -> how to play: instructions on how to play the game in brief terms
    private void howToPlayToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connect Five is quite similar to the good old-fashioned Connect Four, " +
            "but there is a lot more spaces for you to play you pieces and you have to connect " +
            "five to win! The twist is, that you can only win a certain way, dependent on the " +
            "randomly generated direction on the right hand side of the screen. If the direction is " +
            "vertical, then you can only win with 5 coloured squares in a vertical line. Same with " +
            "horizontal and diagonal directions! Have Fun!", "Connect Five: How To Play");
    }
    // help -> about: quick about menu of the game, creator and copyright year/ symbol
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Made by Brendan Ellis © 2019", "Connect Five About");
    }
    // visual studio has a hissy fit if i dont put this in because it recognises this as a menu strip. 
    // This and the button_click function clash and i haven't been able to find a fix.
    private void fileToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    // file -> new game: resets complete game board to have a rematch
    private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        turn = Player.Red;
        turn_count = 0;

        win_method =
            new[] { WinMethod.Horizontal, WinMethod.Vertical, WinMethod.Diagonal }
                .OrderBy(_ => __rnd.Next())
                .First();

        foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            b.Enabled = true;
            b.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
    }
    // file -> exit game: just exits the game because clicking the cross is obviously sooooo last year
    private void exitGameToolStripMenuItem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    // visual studio has a hissy fit if i dont put this in because it recognises this as a menu strip. 
    // This and the button_click function clash and i haven't been able to find a fix.
    private void helpToolStrip_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Enabled)
        {
            b.BackColor = turn == Player.Yellow ? Color.Yellow : Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void button_leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Enabled)
        {
            b.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
    }

    private void resetWinCountersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yellow_win_count.Text = "0";
        red_win_count.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

It will definitively set `winner_found` so you should have the same problem as your existing code.

Comment: i have just copied this into my application and have many build errors with the turn and player entities - operator == cannot be applied to 'bool' and 'player'. The turn entity (line 92) says cannot convert from bool to Connect_Five.Player? and this error vice versa (connect_five.Player to bool) in other areas (line 135)?

Comment: @BrenoJ - You haven't copied my code across correctly. I removed all of the `bool` references. Check my code again.